# I have B1 visa, can I apply for F1 visa?

Tags: b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

I have B1 visa for conferences. Due to some personal reasons I have never traveled to united states before. My B1 visa is still valid. Now, I want F1 visa. would this have effect to get F1 visa, since I haven't traveled with B1?

Best,
Nahom

Comment: [**Related?**](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/28970/2236)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, a friend of mine applied for F1 while holding a valid B1/B2 visa. His F1 was approved but they cancelled his B1/B2 visa.

Regarding not travelling to the US using the visa you issued, there is nothing official regarding this, it will be at the discretion of the interviewer.

Note: I hold two different types of visas now, B1/B2 and D, both are valid and I am using both.